# SharedPreferences service class

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am pretty new to Android and I was wondering the following: 
I want to create a class that manages the `sharedPreferences` for my app.
Basically I want to load and save in this class.
The thing is that I want to save in my SettingsActivity and load in another `Activity`.
Therefore this will be a "service" or some kind.

What do I use best for this class? Does it have to extend `Service`?
Does it have to extend `Activity`? Or does it even have to extend something else? Or maybe nothing?
I guess I will have to pass some values to that class, and the class will have to be able to talk to the `Context` I believe.
For the record, I am not looking for code, but only for a brief explanation on what options I have and what they do exactly :).

Thnaks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharedPreferences are called SharedPreferences because they are shared by different clients within the same process.
"For any particular set of preferences, there is a single instance of this class that all clients share"

When you retrieve the SharedPreferences using [getSharedPreferences(Context, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) you'll have access to the same set of preferences regardless of what component in your app is retrieving the SharedPreferences.

In other words you don't need any special component to save in your SettingsActivity and to read in your other Activity, either save/read the preferences in the Activities itself or use any POJO that does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The class you will create, say `sharedPrefsAccessor`, does not have to extend anything: it will be a simple [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POJO) which has a reference to the Context. Since all edits performed by the `SharedPreferences.editor` are [atomic](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#edit%28%29), you can safely create multiple instances of this accessor in any activity that needs it.